# Importing a 30GB flat text file over internet to local file system using multiple connection to that flat file?

Tags: java, file, download, flat

Lets say, I have a flat text file in a server. I need to download/import/copy to my local file system over internet.  Is there any way I could import the file in chunks or have multiple connection to that flat text file itself from my local system, so that, the import/copy/ becomes faster?

Regards

Comment: He probably hacked Sony once again and wants to download the remaining credit card numbers. :D

Comment: Try zipping (7zip is the best) the file before sending it over.

Comment: @ustun: Too obvious! +1 :)  Compression would result in very significant savings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can do it is if supported by an FTP server available, use a multiple ftp based product that basically divdes it up, downloads multiple streams to the same file. However, in the end there is one stark reality, your speed will still  be only a max of the smallest link along the path. So, if you download the file and get full bandwidth of say 2mb a second, making 10 connections you'll only get say 200k/s each, it wont make it faster unless something throttles the download on a connection by connection basis.

Of course, thats also not using java, but there probably is a java multi FTP thing about.

Comment: What if 10 PCs downloading from a server? I want the original file residing in the server be divided into 10 different chunks and get downloaded to those 10 PCs at a time. Thank you!

Comment: Its still limited by the slowest part - so if all 10 PCs combine, and even if you work out a way to do it, if you only have a band width of 2mb/s to the area those machines are in, 1 machine or 10, its still only 2mb.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do this is probably to email the site administrator at that server, and request that he express post you a hard drive with the data you want, for a fee.

Failing that, you will need to investigate and buy the fastest link to the internet you can find.
 Given that you have a fast link to the internet which will allow you to download data at X bytes per second, then your maximum theoretical limit is X bytes per second.

If you get significantly below X bytes per second, you may be being rate limited, either by the server in question, or any link between you or their server.

If it just happens to be that your ISP is doing the rate limiting, then in that specific case, you *might* be able to download data faster using a second connection and downloading a different portion of the file.

Comment: I have a 50Mb/s Virgin cable broadband connection and frequently get speeds of over 5MB/s when downloading 16GB+ games from Steam. I would be able to download that file in less than 102 minutes, which would be much faster than getting it by post... Even with the [UK average 6.8Mb/s](http://www.thinkbroadband.com/news/4742-ofcom-average-uk-broadband-speeds-rise-to-6-8mbps.html), one should be able to download it in around 12.5 hours, which is much faster than post.

Comment: @Spycho: Wow, an average of 6.8Mb/s?  I'm lucky to get 2Mb/s.  Regardless, the OP is clearly asking about how to get a "very large amount of data" quickly, I've tried to answer the question in such a way that it won't be an obsolete answer in a year or two.